# Who redirects Umlaut domain names in browser to transliterated domain name?

Tags: web, redirect

I have a domain that contains an Umlaut like that:

```
https://spaß.de
```

"ß" may be transliterated to "ss".

Now when I copy and paste this text into Chrome or any other browser, I'm taken to

```
https://spass.de
```

However, the 2 domains have different owners, and the owner of "[https://spaß.de](https://spa%C3%9F.de)" will never get any traffic to his site.

Is there any authority that redirects Umlaut domains to transliterated domains, or is the browser responsible for this? I have tried all kinds of browsers, they all show the same behaviour.

Thank you for any insights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case it's the browser. Browsers consider ß ss Ss sS and SS to all have the same semantic meaning when processing web addresses. You can't reliably distinguish between them in a domain name for a web site. If you want to know the details, this process is called Nameprep.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nameprep

On the other hand, u and ü are considered to not have the same semantic meaning. A domain name should not have an actual ü in it, but browsers can display, as an example, xn--bcher-kva as bücher. The encoding scheme is called Punycode.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode

Comment: Thanks. I can award you in 10 hours from now.